# In App Purchase in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

i have to intregrate in app purchase in my new upcoming application. I am familiar about the purchase part and all, but a bit confused related to the applilcation is purchase or not part. **That is, if a user has once purchased the application and uninstalls the app, again user installs the app again, now how can i know that user has already purchased the particular app or not** ?

Answer (score 1):

You will know it.  Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html) carefully :)

in the sample code

the provide

```
 private class DungeonsPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
        public DungeonsPurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(Update.this, handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingSupported(boolean supported) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
                int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request,
                ResponseCode responseCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreTransactionsResponse(RestoreTransactions request,
                ResponseCode responseCode) {

        }


    }
```

EDIT:

For ready make cake read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231978/1436931) :)